# how to add javascript in head in cmsms

Tags: javascript, cmsmadesimple

I want to add a small redirect javascript on the home page of my website.
I am using CMS made simple platform.
Ho do I edit HEAD tag in CMSMS.
I need to put this javascript in HEAD tag.
How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of research have you done so far? What were your attempts to accomplish your goal?

Answer (score 2):

In admin area:  Layout -> Templates.  Edit your template.
Find the part of the HEAD you want to add javascript to.
Add javascript between these tags:

{literal}
...javascript goes here...
{/literal}

Save template.  (The literal tags are needed so CMS Made Simple knows to interpret any { } as javascript and not Smarty).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have permissions to edit page templates, here is another solution to this:

Go to **Pages -> Select your homepage for editing -> Options-tab -> Page Specific Metadata** and add the javascript block there as maidbloke presented:

```
{literal} <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script> {/literal}
```

This works if your home page template has `{metadata}`-tag in it (which is very likely).

Comment: page specific - very nice.